# DNAStringSet Error Biostrings in R

Tags: string, r, bioinformatics, fasta, bioconductor

I posted this same quandary on Biostars but it seems like traffic is low there so I thought I might pose it here.

I am attempting to import a fasta file of sequences into R using Bioconductor's 'Biostrings' package and the 'DNAStringSet' function but I keep getting the same error:

```
Error in .Call2("new_XString_from_CHARACTER", classname, x, start(solved_SEW),  : 
key 112 (char 'p') not in lookup table
```

My fasta file ("FileName.fa") is comprised of various length sequences, in the following format:

```
>GeneNameOne
CAGACACCCATAGATACAGATAGACAGATAGAGAAGACACCACCACACAATGA
>GeneNameTwo
CGCGACATGAACCCATGATAGACGATGAGACCCCACACACACC
...etc
```

I performed 'grep p FileName.fa' in the Unix terminal, but I received no output.

Does anyone have an idea on what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) (no subscription required). Maybe your file is not a plain text file, despite it's extension?

Comment: That is a good idea, and one I already considered. Unfortunately, the turnaround time for that list is a bit long so I was hoping someone would be able to expedite my inquiry on Stack. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: FWIW, there were two responses (not just mine!) on the mailing list 7 minutes after posting there!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used 'readDNAStringSet' instead like so:

```
FileName <- readDNAStringSet("FileName.fa")
```

And it worked marvelously.

Hope this helps anyone else with similar issues.

Comment: Well, instead of 'DNAStringSet' (http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Biostrings/html/XStringSet-class.html). I mentioned it specifically in the original post. Also, instead of using your convoluted 3-page suggestion you emailed me via the BioC mail list. Thank you for the down vote by the way. It really taught me a valuable lesson.